# PHP JSON Array from mysql

Tags: php, json

im confuse with json structure, here mine

```
{
"kode_pelanggan":"USR-6cs42",
"kode_produk":"1,2",
"nama_produk":"MacBook 2015,iPhone 6s"
}
```

but i can get the value if the structur like that, how can i convert like this using php

```
    {
    "firstkey":"it worked!",
    "secondkey":["item1", "item2", "item3"]
}
```

http://codewithchris.com/code/afsample.json

look at the second key its like this :

```
"secondkey":["item1", "item2", "item3"]
```

and mine like this

```
"nama_produk":"MacBook 2015,iPhone 6s"
```

this my code

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array ($query)){
$response = array('kode_pelanggan' => $data["kode_pelanggan"], 'kode_produk' =>  $data["kode_produk"], 'nama_produk' => $data["nama_produk"]);
echo json_encode($response);
```

how can i make this using PHP?

im despaired here.

Answer (score 0):

If your $data['nama_produk'] is comma seperated value you have to [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it to an array so json_encode can output it as json array

Like this :

```
 while ($data = mysql_fetch_array ($query)){
$response = array('kode_pelanggan' => $data["kode_pelanggan"], 
                  'kode_produk' => $data["kode_produk"],
                  'nama_produk' => explode(',', $data["nama_produk"])
            );
echo json_encode($response);
```